# Recommendation for cheap practical graphics tablet?

Tags: technology-in-education

I am looking for a good, stable and cheap graphics tablet for online math education that you use to use and love to use. I need to prepare remote videos.

Comment: One by Wacom $60 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07S1RR3FR/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apap_cXf5N1nZTiMXN

Comment: xp-pen, $40: https://www.amazon.com/StarG640-Ultrathin-Graphics-Battery-Free-Pressure/dp/B078YR2MTF/

Comment: Shopping questions are generally a poor fit for stackexchange. They have little long-term value, and many SE sites explicitly define them as off-topic.

Comment: GAOMON s620 is also a good choice

Comment: @BenCrowell: This particular question has been coming around repeatedly lately, so in this case I would recommend that we keep this (but close others as duplicates).

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation for a usable, inexpensive drawing tablet would be the XP-Pen StarG40. It's what I've been using this year (in conjunction with Blackboard/Collaborate) and costs about $40 as of this writing. It's the lowest-cost tablet I've seen, and it works reasonably well (there are encoding issues in Collaborate that make it always a bit jittery, but it's perfectly smooth in MS Paint, for example).

At the start of 2020, I got this, and also a somewhat higher-end model from the same brand for my graphical artist partner. To our surprise, the lower-end model actually works quite a bit better. She's used much higher-end Wacom models in the past and certainly think that those give a better experience (at much higher cost). On my recommendation, we got these XP-Pen models for everyone in our mathematics department.

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B078YR2MTF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078YR2MTF)